# Print matrix with divide and conquer

Tags: matrix, divide-and-conquer

I'd like to access every element of a matrix in a divide and conquer method... this is what I tried:

```
void show_matrix(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
{
    g << "startX = " << startX << " endX = " << endX << '\n';
    g << "startY = " << startY << " endY = " << endY << '\n';

    if (startX == endX) {
        g << a[startX][startY] << '\n';
        return;
    }

    if (startY == endY) {
        g << a[startX][startY] << '\n';
        return;
    }

    int midX = startX + (endX - startX)/2;
    int midY = startY + (endY - startY)/2;

    show_matrix(startX, startY, endX, midY);
    show_matrix(startX, midY + 1, endX, endY);
    show_matrix(startX, startY, midX, endY);
    show_matrix(midX + 1, startY, endX, endY);
}
```